# Does anybody know what this font is called?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I have this picture with a text on it and I have to find what font it is written in. Does anybody by any chance seen this font before and know what its called?

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's pretty vague. Clearly it's a brush script font - possibly even the canonical [Brush Script](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/brush-script/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the provided image, it looks like this sample was done on an embroidery machine. The sample also looks a bit skewed (like it's on a hat possibly?). Based on that I'd say this font is most likely something standard like **Brush Script Standard Medium**:

[image]

For future reference, we have some [requirements](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and be sure to include this information on your next inquiry.